# array to array conversion (increase number of dimension and format)

Tags: php, arrays

**input array**

```
$input = array (
"group_name_1" => "audi", 
"group_locations_1" => "tokyo,barcelona,paris", 
"group_quantities_at_locations_1" => "1,2,7", 
"group_name_2" => "ford", 
"group_locations_2" => "london,prag", 
"group_quantities_at_locations_2" => "3,6"
);
```

**needed output form**

```
$target_output = array (
"audi" => array ( "tokyo" => 1, "barcelona" => 2, "paris" => 7 ),
"ford" => array ( "london" => 3, "prag" => 6 )
);
```

**notes 1:**

- number of groups are dynamic (user input). For example, additional to
  "audi" and "ford"; there could be also "toyota", "mercedes".
- Each groups has 3 subinfo: 1-name , 2-locations and 3-quantities for
  locations.
- Sequences in input are always same. 1st name, 2nd locations, 3rd
  quantities.
- Each group has proper order number always in input. (such as
  "group_name_**1** or group_locations_**4**)

**notes 2:** I've read array functions again. And tried various codes but I even couldn't get close.

Can you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that `group_name_x, group_locations_x and group_quantities_at_locations_x` keys alwas exists in your `$input` array

```
$input = array(
    "group_name_1" => "audi",
    "group_locations_1" => "tokyo,barcelona,paris",
    "group_quantities_at_locations_1" => "1,2,7",
    "group_name_2" => "ford",
    "group_locations_2" => "london,prag",
    "group_quantities_at_locations_2" => "3,6"
);

$new_array = array();

foreach ($input as $key => $val) {
    if (strpos($key, 'group_name') !== false) {
        $new_array[$val] = array();
        $group_no = $key[strlen($key) - 1];
        $location_array = explode(',', $input["group_locations_{$group_no}"]);
        $group_quantities_array = explode(',', $input["group_quantities_at_locations_{$group_no}"]);
        $new_array[$val] = array_combine($location_array, $group_quantities_array);
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [audi] => Array
        (
            [tokyo] => 1
            [barcelona] => 2
            [paris] => 7
        )

    [ford] => Array
        (
            [london] => 3
            [prag] => 6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$inputs = array (
    "group_name_1" => "audi", 
    "group_locations_1" => "tokyo,barcelona,paris", 
    "group_quantities_at_locations_1" => "1,2,7", 
    "group_name_2" => "ford", 
    "group_locations_2" => "london,prag", 
    "group_quantities_at_locations_2" => "3,6"
);

$result = array();
foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
    if (!preg_match('/group_name_([0-9]*)/', $key, $matches)) {
         continue;
    }

    $locations = explode(',', $inputs['group_locations_' . $matches[1]]);
    $quantities = explode(',', $inputs['group_quantities_at_locations_' . $matches[1]]);
    $result[$value] = array_combine($locations, $quantities);
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: For readers: this solution also works and maybe more efficiently coded. I accepted the other since i understood the logic and i can modify that code if i need. Thank you so much @Matei Mihai

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `array_walk` like as

```
$result = [];
$chunked = array_chunk($input,3);
array_walk($chunked,function($v) use (&$result){
    $result[$v[0]] = array_combine(explode(",",$v[1]),explode(",",$v[2])); 
});
print_R($result);
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/4qT6J)